# Problem with testing nestjs application. (jest, sequelize raw queries)

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, sequelize.js, nestjs

When i testing my b2b.service.ts, jest is showing me an error. [error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTBR4.png)

But when i starting a project, always good. That error only when i start tests. Could you help me please ? I need to use custom raw queries.

[b2b.service.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Lbb.png)

[db provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKHSd.png)

[b2b.spec.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUJ1X.png)

[raw query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jZsJ.png)

I have no idea, why ? :D